# How to show pretty response when request parameter passed using MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

Tags: spring-boot, scala, jackson

i want to show pretty response in browser when someone pass request parameter like following otherwise not.

```
/api/abc?domain=google.com&pretty=true
```

I found following configuration is working:

```
def jackson2HttpMessageConverter(): MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = {
    val converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper())
    converter.setPrettyPrint(true)
    converter
  }
```

but above config apply to all rest endpoint. how should i do using only on specific endpoint ?

Comment: I got fixed this issue by changing implementation from case classes to class. 
with case class response was not converted to pretty response...Adding this comment for future reference with intent to help someone in scala language.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

add to controller

```
@Autowired
var objectMapper: ObjectMapper
```

in controller method - if `pretty` param is true

```
return objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(yourObject)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, and sorry for my  late reply. actually solution you provided is an alternative. the reason behind my issue is case classes when setting in response.